# In sbt how can I add to classpath when a 3rd party task is run?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm using a jacoco code instrumentation task provided by the sbt-jacoco plugin.  This code creates its own directory in target for compiled classes.  Problem is:  I need some artifacts in the usual classes directory in target to be visible to jacoco.  I need to add to jacoco's classpath before its run.  How can I do this in sbt?

Comment: Sbt should already expose all dependencies to jacoco. If I understand correctly, that's not the case?

Comment: Usually but not in my case.  I'm using Dotty, which generates .tasty files.  jacoco and the sbt-jacoco plugin, doesn't know about these.  The .tasty files are created in target/scala-0.28/classes, but sbt-jacoco uses target/scala-0.28/jacoco/instrumented-classes.  Somewhere I need to tell sbt to add the original classpath (containing the .tasty files) to whatever jacoco needs.